# Difference between the spectrum of hydrogen and black body radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, thermal-radiation, spectroscopy

So I'm learning about blackbody radiation and radiation in general. As I understand it, there are 3 ways to transfer energy/heat: convection, conduction and radiation. In chemistry I also learnt about the emission spectrum of hydrogen. I understand that when light is shot at a bunch of Hydrogen atoms some of the electrons will absorb a specific wavelength and will jump to a higher energy level/orbital and then drop back down releasing energy in the form of light of the same wavelength it absorbed - (wavelength directly corresponds to the level of energy it carries - shorter wavelength means its more wavy which means more energy). Hydrogen only has 1 energy level so depending on the amount of energy an electron absorbs it will go to the 2nd/3rd/4th etc. and then fall back to the 1st level because it only has the first level.

[image]

Below is the black body emission spectrum - it is 2d (2 axis, x and y) compared to the 1d emission spectrum of hydrogen, why? Does the y axis indicate the intensity of the wavelength? But wait - wavelength is already an indicator of intensity/energy.

I do not understand the difference between the absorption spectrum of hydrogen and its (ideal) black body radiation. Why would hydrogen be able to emit all kinds of radiation even though it can only absorb discrete levels of energy? Clearly, the black body radiation spectrum tells me that with varying efficiency, hydrogen could emit all kinds of radiation.

[image]

Comment: There are too many questions in the same post. Try to reduce them. If necessary, you may ask more than one question.

Comment: damn, can i edit post, put them in paragraphs and number them?

Comment: That will not do it. Please focus the question. If you have more, post them.

Comment: done, deleted 2 questions

Comment: Okay, good. Reopened.

Comment: *"Hydrogen only has 1 energy level"* That is incorrect. Hydrogen has a lot of energy levels.

Comment: Also, the y-axis in that plot is defined such that the power $P$ radiated by the blackbody over a range of wavelength $d\lambda$ is $P = d\lambda \cdot y$ . For each wavelength, the energy of a photon at that wavelength is $E = h c / \lambda$, so the power is $P = E \cdot \text{Flux}$ where "flux" means "photons emitted per time". So it's not just the wavelength that determines the power radiated by the blackbody but also the flux, which is taken into account in the y-axis of the plot.

Comment: Besides the obvious duplicate there are also lots of other questions about how blackbody radiation (which describes a spectrum, not a mechanism) arises.